# Turn a json object string into value

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that takes a string, splits it, and the uses `json[key][key2][key3]` formatting. The problem is n is potentially infinite (not literally but needs to written that way)

```
function getJsonValue(json,string) {
    var vals = string.split(".");
    var x = vals.length;
    var string = '';
    while (x != 0) {
      string += "['"+vals[(vals.length-x)]+"']"
        x--
    }
    return string;
}
```

That will produce, for example: `"['condition']['item']['condition']['temp']"`

I need to extract a value from that by attaching it to a json object, like

```
json"['condition']['item']['condition']['temp']"
```

But I don't know how or if that is even possible.

Edit:
The problem is I need any value from a config file to be passed in and then parsed from a returning function. I.e. User knows the value will be condition.item.condition.temp for this specific query. I am trying to write one function that covers everything and pass in config values for what I know to be the output. So, on one query, I might want the condition.item.condition.temp value and on another I might want condition.wind.chill .

Comment: Are you outputting this value to another JavaScript file? If not, I don't believe this current implementation will work. ETA: One possible solution for this is if you generate the string and wish to inject it into a 'script' element in your project using jQuery but that's not elegant.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Is this code not working? Isn't the output what you want? You can also use this notation : `json.key1.key2.key3`

Comment: Can you please sample a JSON and string?

Comment: No, just trying to attach it to an object. I am toying with some other ways to accomplish the task but similar manner, just not using strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand 100% what you're trying to do, but if you're receiving a JS object `json` and a string in the format `field1.field2.field3` and trying to get the value of `json.field1.field2.field3` then you can do something like this:

```
function getJsonValue(json,string) {
    var vals = string.split(".");
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) json = json[vals[i]];
    return json;
}
```

It would work like this for a given object:

```
var obj = { field1: { field2: { field3: "Hello!" } } };
var res = getJsonValue(obj, "field1.field2.field3"); 
console.log(res); // prints Hello
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it kept hanging. No clue why.

Comment: It's not doing any input validation, if you want to share an input sample I can test here. It should work for the example I've sent, but if you give a set of fields that don't exist in the object, it will throw an error although you can easily fix that.

Comment: Yeah, I am not really sure why it isn't working right now. But I am going to mark this the answer because it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

See lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs#get)

```
_.get(json, 'key1.key2.key3')
```

you can build the "path" from your current code and ask lodahs to get the value out for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing an eval?

```
var json = {
    'one': {
        'two': {
            'three': {
                'four': 4
            }
        }
    }
};

alert(eval("json['one']['two']['three']['four']"))
```